# Concatenating original value with query value in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I am trying to something in MySQL that I do in JavaScript/PHP all the time.  I need to concatenate the value of a field in MySQL with a value that is passed into a query from PHP.  For example, let's say I have a field called `favourites` with a value of `27` and I have this query:

```
UPDATE useraccs SET favourites = favourites + ',30' WHERE id='10'
```

My desired new value for `favourites` would be `27,30`, but I'm getting `57`, where clearly SQL is adding them numerically.  I have set the data type for this column as TEXT and was hoping that would force SQL to treat it as a string all the time, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

In my research I read about the CONCAT() function, and I tried this:

```
UPDATE useraccs SET favourites = CONCAT(favourites,',30') WHERE id='10'
```

That results in a failed query.  The logic feels right but that is obviously not how that function is meant to be used.

I acknowledge that in theory, I could just grab the original value of `favourites` and concatenate it with the new value in the PHP itself and then send it to MySQL, but I feel like there MUST be a way to do this in one query...if I'm wrong about that so be it, but I'm sure there must be a way.

Comment: what is the type of favourites column? Is it int?

Comment: As I mention in the post, it is the TEXT type.

Comment: I don't believe you for the adding. Could you, by any chance, have written that like `$sql = "UPDATE ... SET favourites = " . $favourites + ',30' . " .... ;";`

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Your id is a string? What is the error? What type of column is favorites

Comment: For the first one I tried, MySQL doesn't give me an error, it just says "0 rows effected"

Comment: The second one just worked.  I honestly have no idea what I changed...this could definitely be closed...

Comment: Now it isn't working when I try it from my PHP.  This is literally what I have written: `$query = "UPDATE useraccs SET favourites = CONCAT(favourites,'$post') WHERE id=$user";`

Comment: When I run that, `mysqli_query` returns false.  My ID is an INT, and `favourites` is TEXT

Comment: I figured out the problem.  I was passing in the wrong variable to `mysqli_query`.  Sorry to waste your time, I feel tremendously silly right now -.-

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to create '27,30':

> CONVERT(favourites,char) + ',30'